# Bootstrap CDN Not Loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A simple yet annoying error.. I can't load the Bootstrap css using the cdn
Here is the simple code

```
         <html>
         <head>
<title>Header template</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </head>
  <body>
<button class="btn btn-default">Hello World</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What's the sign that it's not loading? (And have you tried it with a DOCTYPE declaration?) Also: how are you viewing this page? If you're using a local `file://` URL, you may find that the `//...` protocol-relative URLs aren't working.

Comment: What is the current protocol of your site? `http`, `https` or do you load locally with `file`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things might cause this:

- The obvious one is that you should remove the spaces in the first link (looks like you already edited that)

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
- How are you viewing this file? If it is not served via a webserver (and thus over http of https) then the protocol-less links won't work. 
  Does your browser say `file:///` etc in the address bar? Then add `http://` in front of `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @thanks Deef.. I guess this is right explanation for this.. because when I run it using local server i didn't add **http:**. I will follow this rule form now onwards.. thanks

Comment: great answer. For me, explicitly stating https:// rather than just // fixed it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Add the the Href with HTTP request. Use this may help you and solve your problem

```
<html>
         <head>
<title>Header template</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </head>
  <body>
<button class="btn btn-default">Hello World</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @thanks Muhammad that solved my problem.. but i have used it without http in cnd and it works fine.. Can you please tell me the root cause of this?

Comment: Yes i test it here, and its fine without http , but some time you have to define the protocol.

Comment: but i suggest its much better if you can download these all js and css files to your local project file. it will helps you to work without the internet connection.

Comment: can you please provide him reason, why he will need to add there `http` OR `https`.

Comment: @Girish see my another ans for explanation

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of the “http:” or “https:” part is partly just a matter of tradition, partly a matter of actually specifying the protocol. If it is defaulted, the protocol of the current page is used; e.g., //www.example.com becomes http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com depending on the URL of the referring page. If a web page is saved on a local disk and then opened from there, it has no protocol (just the file: pseudo-protocol), so URLs like //www.example.com won’t work; so here’s one reason for including the “http:” or “https:” part.

Omitting also the “//” part is a completely different issue altogether, turning the URL to a relative URL that will be interpreted as relative to the current base URL.

The reason why www.example.com works when typed or pasted on a browser’s address line is that relative URLs would not make sense there (there is no base URL to relate to), so browser vendors decided to imply the “http://” prefix there.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the date and time problem. My date and time were not correct and when I visited the cdn link I got the date and time error. After correcting it was working fine.